# Passing model from get method to a post nulls the model

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I pass model to the view on the post method the ProductId and UserId get nulled.

```cs
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddReview(int id)
        {
            var userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

            var model = new AddReviewViewModel()
            {
                ProductId = id,
                UserId = userId
            };

            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddReview(AddReviewViewModel addReviewViewModel)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(addReviewViewModel);
            }
            //...
        }
```

Here is how I call the post method.

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 offset-lg-2 col-lg-8 offset-xl-3 col-xl-6">
        <form asp-action="AddReview" method="post">
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label asp-for="@Model.Comment" class="form-label">Comment</label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.Comment" class="form-control" aria-required="true" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Comment" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label asp-for="@Model.Rating" class="form-label">Rating</label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.Rating" class="form-control" aria-required="true" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Rating" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit Review" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have done something like this while adding a new product but I haven't had any problem.

Comment: "If ModelState _is not_ valid ..." - Not sure, but could it be reset because of the "invalid" state?

Comment: Can you show us the code where you call that post method?

Comment: SubKey={UserId}, Key="UserId", ValidationState=Invalid
This the invalid state

Comment: @Silvermind There you go, I have edited the post by adding the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return the data. It needs to make a round-trip. This is typically done with hidden input fields.

```
<input type="hidden" id="ProductId" name="ProductId" value="@Model.ProductId">
<input type="hidden" id="UserId" name="UserId" value="@Model.UserId">
```

Full example

```
<form asp-action="AddReview" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="ProductId" name="ProductId" value="@Model.ProductId">
    <input type="hidden" id="UserId" name="UserId" value="@Model.UserId">
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label asp-for="@Model.Comment" class="form-label">Comment</label>
        <input asp-for="@Model.Comment" class="form-control" aria-required="true" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Comment" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label asp-for="@Model.Rating" class="form-label">Comment</label>
        <input asp-for="@Model.Rating" class="form-control" aria-required="true" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Rating" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit Review" />
    </div>
</form>
```

If your version supports taghelpers you can also write:

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="ProductId">
<input type="hidden" asp-for="UserId">
```

Or using the HtmlHelper:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ProductId)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserId)
```

In all cases, make sure you add this inside the form.